# FileManager.default.enumerator causes crash when attempting to access unreadable URL

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

On the face of it, it seems like one should take care when creating directory enumerators, but my code takes a url chosen by the user and it is possible to pick a protected folder in the NSOpenPanel which is then passed in to create the directory enumeration. For example, the user could choose the `User/Guest/Desktop` folder which is unreadable by a non-guest user.

My handling code (once the url[s] are chosen) is:

```
if let enumerator: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: the_url, includingPropertiesForKeys: [URLResourceKey.isReadableKey], options: [.skipsHiddenFiles, .skipsPackageDescendants], errorHandler: { (unreadable_url, error) -> Bool in
  print ("Enum error")
  DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: { () -> Void in
    self.setStatusText("Cant read url", colour: .red) //Code to update UI on main thread
  error_occured = true
})
  return false
}) {
    //process contents
    while let nested_item = enumerator.nextObject() { //....<Crashes
      // ..
    }
}
```

Thing is if the url is unreadable (typically because it's protected) then the app crashes at the `while..` line with **error**.

> Thread 6: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

No other information is output in Xcode's console. It appears that the `enumerator` ivar passes the non-nil test despite being unusable and the error block isn't executed so the `while` statement fails.

My solution has been to check the `URLResourceKey.isReadableKey` prior to the `if let..` line, but that seems like a double-check which shouldn't be necessary.

Is my code wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: The method `nextObject()` returns `Any?` you need to cast your object from Any to URL. `while let nested_item = enumerator.nextObject() as? URL {`

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: So you're right to point out the inclusion of  `as? URL` but it doesn't solve why I need - effectively - two checks prior to enumeration: resolving security bookmark and checking if it's readable. The code will crash without this second check.